# Html.ValidationSummary(true) does not display Ivalidatable errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have a Razor view with a Html.ValidationSummary(true) tag.

Property level validation is executing fine and the messages display next to the field in error. However for validation by the Validate method implementing IValidatable I have an issue.

If the model itself implements IValidatable then the error is added to the modelstate and correctly displayed at the Html.ValidationSummary(true) tag (Model level error not Property level)
IF however the view model contains a reference to a complex object (Decorated with [Required] annotation) then the message does NOT display. It is added to the ModelState and isValid correctly becomes false. It is in the list of errors and shows as being a model level error BUT does not display. (If you use Html.ValidationSummary(false) then the message displays).

Is this just not doable? Am I doing something wrong? Debating moving to Fluent, but that is more work again....

Here is an example of the code:
View Model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public TestModel DataModel { get; set; }
}
```

TestModel:

```
public class TestModel : IValidatableObject
{

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(ViewResources), Name = "Field1")]
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Field3 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Field1) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Field2))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Need to enter either Field1 or Field2.");
        }
    }
}
```

Razor View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "createDialog" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataModel.Field1)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataModel.Field1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataModel.Field1)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataModel.Field2)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataModel.Field2)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataModel.Field2)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataModel.Field3)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataModel.Field3)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataModel.Field3)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

Controller:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View();
    return View();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a clean implementation, but still you can use this.

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {  
                System.Web.Mvc.ModelState modelStateObj = new ModelState();
                bool isModelStateAvailable = ModelState.TryGetValue("DataModel", out modelStateObj);
                if (isModelStateAvailable)
                {
                    ModelState.Remove("DataModel");
                    modelStateObj.Errors.ToList().ForEach(t => { ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, t.ErrorMessage); });
                }                
            }
```